# How do I convert any file to my own encoding?

Tags: c++, zip

I need a way to open the file and replace each character with my own

so far, I've only figured out how to open the file and output it to the console, but I need a way to compress the data, so I want to start by replacing each character with my own

// file can be any not only `.jpg`, but also `.png`, `.bin` or even `.exe`

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream fs("test.jpg", std::ios::binary);

    if (fs) {
        std::cout << " Yes " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << " No " << std::endl;
    }

    char s;


    for (fs >> s; !fs.eof(); fs >> s)
        std::cout << s;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if you could show me how to replace the file data with your own.
and then I also want to change the data back to get the original file.

Comment: What does "replacing with my own" mean?  Like randomly,  or reimplementing some cipher?

Comment: Take a look at std::ofstream to write to files.

Comment: @Quimby Yes, in a certain way, for example, the symbol `65 - 01000001b` (`0x41`)`A` will be the number `10214` or some other thing that I will come up with, but it will be 100% of the number